# Encrypt password using executable file to be call in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, encryption, exe

I am trying to re-engineer a process that I have inherited. I have a batch file with contents similar to:
execbatch -d DOMAIN -f "D:\exec_eta.bat"

execbatch is a executable file that has the encrypted password for the exec_eta.bat.

Inside exec_eta.bat the code is written as:
"D:\etautil" -d %1 -u %2 -p %3 -f "D:\Data.eta" >> "D:\Data.out"

This is where the etautil script get processed using the encrypted domain, username, and password stored in execbatch.

How can I re-create this execbatch?

Comment: What do you mean by recreate? Do you simply want to re-implement the functionality, or do you want to be able to access the files previously encrypted for "execbatch" - if its the latter, you'll need to know the algorithm, packaging and password.

Comment: re implement the functionality.

Comment: Have you used a utility like `procexp` from Sysinternals to inspect the command line? That would reveal the value of the -d parameter. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx